# Name of a widget in spreadsheet software used to drag formulas to other cells

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, computing

You can find it in all spreadsheet applications like Microsoft Excel, LibreOffice Calc or Google Docs. In the [Help pages of the latter](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/75509), it is described as:

> a small blue box in the lower right corner [of the cell]

[image: small blue box in the lower right corner]

Is there any name given to that widget? How do people normally refer to it when talking to other people? For example:

> – How do I copy this formula to other cells in the column?
>
> – Just click and drag this [insert name here] downwards.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is standard English rather than technobabble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft calls it the **Fill Handle**, as seen [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Copy-a-formula-by-dragging-the-fill-handle-in-Excel-2016-for-Mac-dd928259-622b-473f-9a33-83aa1a63e218).

[image]

Comment: [Confirmed too in this video](https://youtu.be/0nbkaYsR94c?t=4m52s) by the guy that ran the Excel team before starting this website :)

Comment: In casual speaking among Excel users it's also likely to just be referred to as "the handle"